# Form2_KeyPress not firing (Windows Forms App, C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, input

I'm currently trying to make a bare-bones game using windows forms app, but I'm having an issue getting user input. Below is a snippet of code:

```
private void Form2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Random Rand = new();
            
            DEBUG.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                DEBUG.Text = $"{Rand.Next(1,100)}";
            });
        }
```

DEBUG is the textbox which I'm trying to change once the user presses any key. I have checked other similar questions posted to stack overflow, however I have been unable to find an answer. Form2 has KeyPreview set to True.

Comment: You need to set `KeyPreview = true` -- Remove that `.Invoke()` stuff -- Declare the Random object as a static Field

Comment: Are you subscribed to the KeyDown event? Here's an example similar to what you're doing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=windowsdesktop-7.0